# Resize JPanel and JPopupMenu automatically on JPanel expand

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jpopupmenu

I am currently facing a small issue that goes like this: I have a button which, when clicked, will trigger the display of a JPopupMenu under it ( I grab the location of the button, substract a bit from it's height and display the JPopupMenu). This is all made in NetBeans with the GUI builder.

The JPopupMenu is composed of several JPanels, which contain a JLabel, a Button, a TextField and a CheckBox. Those JPanels, I want them to be first initialized in a "minimized" mode( display only the label), but, when the user clicks on them, to expand and display the other components as well. On a second click, the JPanel will revert to the "minimized" state.

Now, I don't know exactly where the issue is, whether in the way the JPanel is resized or not, but although when I click the button the popup menu is displayed correctly and everything else, if I expand a JPanel inside it, the popup menu does not get resized -> it has the same width/height no matter what I do. I tried to change the Layout Manager used by JPopupMenu to FlowLayout,BoxLayout, but ultimately they had no effect. Now, a few snippets of points of interest in the code:

```
public class WifiItem extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private final Dimension maxDimension;
private final Dimension minDimension;
private boolean maximized;

public WifiItem() {
    initComponents();
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    maxDimension = new Dimension(386, 62);
    minDimension = new Dimension(386, 32);
    maximized = false;
    setSize(minDimension);
    setPreferredSize(minDimension);
    setMinimumSize(minDimension);
    setMaximumSize(minDimension);
    this.setPreferredSize(minDimension);
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (maximized) {
                setToMin();
            } else {
                setToMax();
            }
        }
    });

}

public final void setToMax() {
    setSize(maxDimension);
    setPreferredSize(maxDimension);
    setMinimumSize(maxDimension);
    setMaximumSize(maxDimension);
    maximized = true;
    getParent().revalidate();
}

public final void setToMin() {
    setSize(minDimension);
    setPreferredSize(minDimension);
    setMinimumSize(minDimension);
    setMaximumSize(minDimension);
    maximized = false;
    getParent().revalidate();

}
```

This is where I build the JPopupMenu and set up the display.

```
public class WifiConnections {

private static final List<WifiItem> connectionsList = new ArrayList<>();
public static JPopupMenu displayPanel;

public WifiConnections() {
    displayPanel = new JPopupMenu();
    displayPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(displayPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    WifiItem newItem = new WifiItem();
    newItem.setConnectionId("Connection 1.");
    WifiItem newItem2 = new WifiItem();
    newItem2.setConnectionId("Connection 2.");
    connectionsList.add(newItem);
    connectionsList.add(newItem2);
    connectionsList.forEach((item) -> {
        displayPanel.add(item);
    });
}

public void displayPopup(Point p) {
    displayPanel.setLocation(p.x, p.y + 34);
    displayPanel.setVisible(true);
}

public void hidePopup() {
    displayPanel.setVisible(false);
}
```

}

[image: When the popup menu is displayed]
[image: When item is expaneded]

As you can see, if I expand one item, the other one gets covered and the popup does not resize to fit the JPanels, and I am really at a loss at how to continue.

Comment: Use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: "I tried to change the Layout Manager used by JPopupMenu to FlowLayout,BoxLayout, but ultimately they had no effect."

Comment: "The JPopupMenu is composed of several JPanels, which contain a JLabel, a Button, a TextField and a CheckBox"  - I don't see it in the code posted. Also the code does not compile (`initComponents();` ? ) Please post [mcve]